# find corresponding key,values and return?

Tags: python

```
I have a dictionary 

cities  = {1:'Kompong Som', 2: 'Kompong Thom', 3: 'Phnom Penh'}
tags = {1: 'school', 2: 'public', 3: 'private'}

kwargs = {'city': '2', 'tag': '3'}#should be improve
```

I want to get output like this :

```
kwargs = {'city': 'Kompong Thom', 'tag': 'private'}
```

EDIT 
passed from URL

```
 keyword = customer_type=&last_contact=&tag=2,3&city=3&sale_volume=&acc_creation=&last_sale=&key_comm=
```

in this case

```
tag=2,3&city=3 maybe in other case tag=2&city=1,2,3 or tag=1,2,3&city=1,2,3

def present_filter(self, list_result, keyword):
    #@todo: the present filter should be friendly with user .
       if len(list_result) > 0:
           keywords = eval(json.dumps(keyword))

           new_keywords = {}
           for key,value in keywords.items():
                if value != '' :
                    new_keywords[key] = value
           return new_keywords
          # Now new_keywords is {'city': '3', 'tag': '2,3'}
          # I WANT TO BE LIKE THIS
          #new_keywords is {'city': 'Phnom Penh', 'tag': 'public,private'}
       else:
           return ''
```

Comment: get real.. are you sure this isn't homework? you need a book on python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def translate(cities, tags, kwargs):
  return {'city': cities[int(kwargs['city'])],
          'tag': tags[int(kwargs['tag'])]}
```

There's no clear way (from your question) to automate the keyname-to-auxiliary dictionary choice, so I've just hardcoded the keys and aux dict to use for each; if that's not what you want, please edit your question to clarify what it *is* that you want!-)

**Edit**: so given this new and different spec from the OP:

```
      # Now new_keywords is {'city': '3', 'tag': '2,3'}
      # I WANT TO BE LIKE THIS
      #new_keywords is {'city': 'Phnom Penh', 'tag': 'public,private'}
```

the solution becomes:

```
def commaplay(adict, value):
  return ','.join(adict[int(x)] for x in value.split(','))

def translate(cities, tags, kwargs):
  return {'city': commaplay(cities, kwargs['city']),
          'tag': commaplay(tags, kwargs['tag'])}
```

Of course, if the OP completely changes their specs again, the solution will change once more in response (wouldn't it be just **incredibly great** if people **said what they meant**, *and* **meant what they said**, instead of whirling things around all the time?!-).

Comment: @Alex Martelli ,thank for your help and comments.it's what I want .

Comment: @Alex Martelli  I read about at http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/au/918
You are super ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could put `cities` and `tags` in a helper dictionary to make it more easy to select the correct values using the `kwargs` keys:

```
choices = {
   'city': cities,
   'tag':  tags
}

result = {}
for k, v in kwargs:
   result[k] = choices[k][int(v)]
```